# Unexpected Error when trying to delete attachment

Tags: error-handling

I am having a user reporting **unexpected error** when trying to delete the attachment from a list item. I have gone through the log files,but not able to find any trace of the error. I am kind of new to SharePoint. This is happening in SharePoint 2007.

This is happening when I try to delete a file from an item field and click on ok. It's spinning for quite amount of time and throwing the error.
Please help me with this.

Also when trying to save the list as template it says the below message(Include content checked).

The list is too large to save as a template. The size of a template cannot exceed 10485760 bytes.

Comment: Is the attachment on the local machine or on a shared drive? We get the error sometimes when the attachment is on the shared drive. I have no solution at this point...

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find a solution to this problem.
This is specific to the list hence I was thinking about debugging the whole code which was not at all the smart way of doing it.
One of my colleagues has tested the list item fields and found out the cause.
She tested out all the fields by adding and deleting each fields content.
When she added some new users deleting previous users in the people picker group, I was able to edit the list fields without error.
It was because it was allowing users to be added in the assigned to list field even though they were not in the company anymore/ they don't have access to it.

Answer (score 0):

> > The list is too large to save as a template. The size of a template cannot exceed 10485760 bytes.

Use [stsadm to increase quota](http://blogs.technet.com/b/sharepointcomic/archive/2008/04/07/increase-maximum-size-of-list-template.aspx)

```
stsadm -o setproperty -propertyname max-template-document-size -propertyvalue 50000000
```